# How to add a class attribute to sitecore MVC image field

Tags: model-view-controller, sitecore

Using Sitecore mvc field render

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("FieldName", ContentItem)
```

I would like to add class to image tag like below,

```
<img src="/images/Sample.jpg" class="hidden-xs">
```

So, How can I add the css class in Site core MVC image field.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

You can simply use this one.

```
@Html.Sitecore().Field("FieldName", Model.PageItem, new { @class="large-image", @mw="250" })
```

Comment: Thanks for your  reply

Comment: In above syntax getting parameter count mismatch error.

Comment: I updated, please use this: `@Html.Sitecore().Field("FieldName", Model.PageItem, new { @class="large-image", @mw="250" })` in your view.

Comment: how to specify a style class to @Html.Glass().Editable()