# How to add a class attribute to Sitecore MVC Link Field without overwriting the style class

Tags: razor, sitecore

Based on the question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36092433/how-to-add-a-class-attribute-to-sitecore-mvc-image-field), I can successfully render a field with a class attribute.

For example, I have a list of link fields that are being rendered with the Bootstrap class `nav-link`. However, if any of the links have `Style class:` defined in Sitecore, setting the `nav-link` class will overwrite the style class, rather than add to it.

How can I add the nav-link class without overwriting any classes added through Sitecore?

Example code:

> @Html.Sitecore().Field("Link", navItem, new { @class = "nav-link" })

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered the answer by casting the field as a `LinkField` as follows:

`@Html.Sitecore().Field("Link", navItem, new {
     @class = "nav-link " + ((LinkField)navItem.Fields["Link"]).Class,
     text = Html.Sitecore().Field("Link Text", navItem)
})`

As can be seen in the code above, we simply concatenate the desired class with `((LinkField)navItem.Fields["Link"]).Class`, and that gives us both classes on the field.